# Prohibited symbol in Ubuntu desktop

Tags: 20.04, gnome

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, GNOME version 40.4.0 and windowing system=Wayland.

I'm getting this prohibited symbol now and then since I upgraded to GNOME 40, but I don't know when this problem started exactly. It shows up few times a minute and the terminal freezes. Pressing the Super key twice unfreezes the terminal.

[image]

Comment: Hii, i think outdated snaps are causing this issue.. i updated all snaps from snapstote (software) and now... Almost, it's gone..! Will update if it repeats...

Comment: I'm getting it again. Is there anyone who knows the reason??